# Hide all elements within a class that don't match the ID of a variable

Tags: javascript

I have a site with tiles much like the Windows 10 Start menu.

I need these tiles to have fullwidth drop downs once clicked, I'll need the dropdown to close if the same tile is clicked again and I need one dropdown to close others if a different tile is clicked.

These tiles will have all sorts of names so I was hoping to create some javascript that would be dictated by the ID of the tile clicked.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<div id="gaming" class="box one-one blue" onclick="showSection(this);">
<div id="gaming-section" class="section">

<div id="marketing" class="box one-one blue" onclick="showSection(this);">
<div id="marketing-section" class="section">
```

```js
function showSection(obj) {
    var tileName =obj.getAttribute('id');
    var sectionName =(tileName+'-section');
    document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "block";
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why the Java question tag? What does this problem have to do with Java programming?

Comment: The jQuery and HTML tags seem pretty redundant too, given the code sample and goal

Comment: please consider closing your div tags

Answer (score 0):

exchange `document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "block";` for this:

```
const elemStyle = document.getElementById(sectionName);

if (elem.style.display !== 'block') {
    elem.style.display = 'block';
else {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
    elements.forEach(elem => {
        elem.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is completing half the job of hiding the DIV when the same tile is clicked again, how would I go about hiding all DIV's that don't match the 'SectionName' variable?

Comment: I can't seem to get this new code to work. I added a missing '}' but there seems to be a missing ')' on that last line: 'elements.forEach(elem => {
        elem.style.display = 'none';
    }'